# How call the object from an other swift file

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, callback, wkwebview

I build an iOS app with Swift. And how can get/call the webview object from the 'mainviewcontroller', if the button for the 'previous' web page is in an other swift file 'widgetcontroller'.

In 'mainviewcontroller' file with the 'webview' object.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var webView : WKWebView!  
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    }

    @IBAction func history(sender: AnyObject) {
        webView?.goBack()
    }
}
```

The other file that are the buttons.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class WidgetViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.booktransitionManager.sourceViewController = self
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

     @IBAction func goprevious(sender: AnyObject) {
            MainViewController.history()
        }
}
```

goprevious -> that is linked to a button "touch up" action.

When I run this, it crash the iPhone app. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: the usual way is to implement a protocol and a delegate. There are many examples how to do that

Comment: You need to somehow have a reference to your `MainViewController` . This can be achieved in a number of different ways. Please post more context and code.

Comment: @pe60t0 see update code with MainViewController

Comment: Yeah you can't do that - its invalid to call the history() method like this. Read about how to use the delegate pattern. Basically you will need an object to delegate the goprevious() method back to the `MainViewController` . Out of curiosity - what do you mean by 'other file that are the buttons' ? How are these view controllers presented ?

Comment: You can easily find how to use the delegation pattern in objective-c/swift on the internet

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in any of following ways:

1. Send a notification when the second controller is going away and have the parent listen for it. as:

Add Observer:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "viewHistory:",
    name: "ViewHistory",
    object: nil)
```

Observer Method:

```
@objc func viewHistory(notification: NSNotification){     
    //do stuff
}
```

Call Notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ViewHistory", object: nil)
```

2. Create a delegate protocol that lets the second controller reference a parent method directly.
3. Use the parent's viewWillAppear: and check the isMovingToParentViewController property for whether it's just re-appearing.

and apply what is best for your value passing conditions and availability of values.

Comment: Is that helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` as follow

```
//For add observer
@IBAction func goprevious(sender: AnyObject) {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "history:", name: "give_name_of_observer", object: nil)
}

//For remove observer
 @IBAction func history(sender: AnyObject) {
      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "give_name_of_observer", object: nil)
}
```